# Purescript Thermite - Updating state using record types

Tags: reactjs, purescript

I am trying to understand why the updated state is not visualized.

```
type State = {a :: Int, b :: Int}

data Action
  =  IncrementA | IncrementB

render :: T.Render State _ Action
render perform props state _ =
    [
          text (show (toNumber props.a))
          ,button [ RP.className "btn btn-success"
                   , RP.onClick \_ -> perform IncrementA
                  ]
                  [ text (show (toNumber props.a))]
         , button [ RP.className "btn btn-danger"
                   , RP.onClick \_ -> perform IncrementB
                  ]
                  [ text (show (toNumber props.b)) ]
    ]


performAction :: forall e. T.PerformAction _ State _ Action
performAction IncrementA                _ _ = void do
  T.cotransform \state -> state {a = state.a + 1}
performAction IncrementB                _ _ = void do
  T.cotransform \state -> state {b = state.b + 1}


komponent :: T.Spec _ State _ Action
komponent = T.simpleSpec performAction render

main :: Eff (dom :: DOM) Unit
main = void do
  let state = {a: 0 , b :0}
  let component = T.createClass komponent state
  document <- DOM.window >>= DOM.document
  container <-
    unsafePartial
    (fromJust <<< toMaybe
    <$> DOM.querySelector "#container"
    (DOM.htmlDocumentToParentNode document))
  RDOM.render
    (R.createFactory component (state))
    container
```

(The entire code can be found in https://github.com/MarkusBarthlen/electron-apps-with-purescript)

I can confirm using logging that the state is updated. Also, if I rewrite everything as in Lesson 4 (http://paf31.github.io/try-thermite/?gist=c1b9c6fc5f012cfe8f0f), the gui is updated.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Nevermind, using pux it seems to work (https://github.com/MarkusBarthlen/electron-apps-with-purescript/commit/128c00e055024c939861edd082167bfa8939b0ac)

Comment: Also, it should have said state.a etc. and not props.a. I assumed this was because of react. Turns out it is just a regular error.